# Handle access of Dynamic view in table row in android

Tags: android

actually i add a row in table by clicking on add button in activity. when we click on add row get added in table. row contains some edittext and one delete button. i want to delete particulate row by click delete. but their are multiple row with same views. so plz tell me how to knows which row's delete button get click to remove that row from table.

i will add one sample image of wallet. i want handle like that.
[image: Just for example]

added view also one table row. i just added it by table.addView(view); method

Answer (score 0):

You should get buton like this in addview method. and then give click listener to that button.

```
Button btnDelete = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
btnDelete.setTag(id);
```

When you are adding views in Row. just set any Unique identifier to them.like:

```
btnDelete.setTag(id);
```

so this way you can identify which button is clicked in click event. like this:

```
String tag = view.getTag();
```

Now, you know which views to remove.so do the work to remove them.

Hope it Helps!!!

Comment: thanx.. but i add row in table which also a one table row view. and i add one onclick method on that button but method get called each time when i click. i could not find which views button clicked.

Comment: sure... can u give me your mail id.

Comment: you are adding view to table row. but you haven't added click event of delete button. then how can you get click event?? have you got click event of button delete??